# Block with non ARC, memory leak issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Could you help me with this error.
I've tried this code, with ARC and non ARC.
with ARC is OK. but with non ARC.
How could I do. help me please. ^__^;

When I push the button, the error occures.
**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    void                    (^_myOne)(void);    
    UIView*                 _viewOne;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)   void            (^myOne)(void);
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIView*         viewOne;
- (void)useFirstOne:(void(^)(void))blockOne;
@end
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize myOne = _myOne, viewOne = _viewOne;
- (void)useFirstOne:(void (^)(void))blockOne {

    blockOne ();
}
- (void)buttonPressed {
        [self useFirstOne:self.myOne]; //If I put this line into 'viewDidLoad', has no problem.
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIButton* buttonA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buttonA.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
    buttonA.center = CGPointMake(160, 350);
    [buttonA setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonA addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonA];
    _viewOne = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewOne];

    _myOne = ^{
        self.viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    };
}
@end
```

**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
_myOne = ^{
    self.viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
};
```

needs to be this:

```
_myOne = Block_copy(^{
    self.viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
});
```

This is because block objects are **stack allocated**, which means that they are deallocated when they go out of scope. So when the `viewDidLoad` method finishes executing, the block held in `_myOne` will be deallocated, and if you try to use it it will crash. When you copy a block, the copy is **heap allocated** and will survive until it is released.